# Create input field dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using `yii2` framkework and on based of input provided by user I want to create `input` fields. Using some online documents [like this](http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/) I tried to do it but the problem is my `button` click event is not picking up the `jquery`

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xukh1vgh/) for it. Not able to replicate my problem exactly but what i want is if user enters 3 in the input field than 3 field should be generated on button click.

Here is my `view` code

```
<div class="event-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'form-event']); ?>  

<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'start_date')->widget(
            DatePicker::className(), [
            'name' => 'start_date',
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Event start date ...'],
            'convertFormat' => true,
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'orientation' => 'bottom left',
                'format' => 'MM/dd/yyyy',
                'startDate' => date('dd-MM-yyyy'),
                'autoclose' => true,
                'todayHighlight' => true
            ]
        ])
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'end_date')->widget(
            DatePicker::className(), [
            'name' => 'end_date',
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Event end date...'],
            'convertFormat' => true,
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'orientation' => 'bottom left',
                'format' => 'MM/dd/yyyy',
                'startDate' => date('dd-MM-yyyy'),
                'autoclose' => true,
                'todayHighlight' => true
            ]
        ])
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <button type="button" id="setdates" class="btn btn-default btn-set-dates">Set Dates</button>
    </div>
</div>

<p></p>

<p></p>
<div class="form-group hide" id="optionTemplate">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-5">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="option[]" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-danger' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Here is the `javascript` i am using

```
$('#setdates').click(function() {
startDate = new Date(document.getElementById('event-start_date').value);
endDate = new Date(document.getElementById('event-end_date').value);
var dates = [],
    currentDate = startDate,
    addDays = function(days) {
        var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
        return date;
    };
while (currentDate <= endDate) {
    dates.push(currentDate);
    currentDate = addDays.call(currentDate, 1);
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var MAX_OPTIONS = 5;
  $('#form-event')

    .on('click', '.setdates', function() {
        var $template = $('#optionTemplate'),
            $clone    = $template
                .clone()
                .removeClass('hide')
                .removeAttr('id')
                .insertBefore($template),
            $option   = $clone.find('[name="option[]"]');

    })
    // Called after adding new field
    .on('added.field.fv', function(e, data) {
        if (data.field === 'option[]') {
            if ($('#event-form').find(':visible[name="option[]"]').length >= MAX_OPTIONS) {
            }
        }
    })

});
```

So I have to generate input fields for the `dates` times.

Comment: Could you provide us with a minmal, failing example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Oleander i have added the jsfiddle and its not exactly what problem i am having but if someone can solve that than i will do the rest

Comment: I'm only getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`.

Comment: @oleander look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tymjjngd/) and can you please tell me how to change the label dynamically as well? like option 1 option 2 ,option 3 etc

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<a id="add">Add More</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var i = 1;
$("#add").click(function(){
                var appendFields = '<tr>';
                appendFields += '<td><select id="dropdown_'+i+'" name="dropdown_name[]"><option value="1">One</option></select></td>';
                appendFields += '<td><a style="color: red; cursor: pointer;" class="remCF">Remove</a></td>';
                appendFields += '</tr>';
                $("#table_id").append(appendFields);
                i++;
            });
            $("#table_id").on('click','.remCF',function(){
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });

        });
```

Comment: i want it to be created based on the inputs provided by user.

Answer (score 1):

might be you document is not ready when your js file will laod.
replace "#form-event" with "document"
make sure ".setdates" this class you will not use for other dom if you use this class this click will occur for every dom which has ".setdates" class and #setdates

```
$(document).on('click','#setdates',(function() {});


 $(document)
    .on('click', '.setdates', function() {
        var $template = $('#optionTemplate'),
            $clone    = $template
                .clone()
                .removeClass('hide')
                .removeAttr('id')
                .insertBefore($template),
            $option   = $clone.find('[name="option[]"]');

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I am posting sample code which may help you. You might have to modify it according to your need to use.

The **HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="numPpl" name="numPpl">
<br><br>
<div id="demo">

</div>
```

The **JQuery**

```
<script>
    $('#numPpl').blur(function()
    {
        for(i=1; i<=$('#numPpl').val(); i++)
        {
            $('#demo').append('<input type="text"><br><input type="text"><br><br>');
        }
    });
</script>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovoqnr2n/)**

Comment: that is really helpful and makes it easy but i also wants to validate those fields and for that i have to make bootstrap forms so that i can use its `.formvalidation` method

Comment: that's why in the beginning I told 'You might have to modify it according to your need'.. :-)